# How to find the ordered pairs and range from the function $a: \{12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \to\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $a: \{12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the function defined by $a(x)$ equals the largest prime number that divides $x$.
>
> a) Write down the set of ordered pairs which corresponds to $a$.
>
> b) What is the range of $a$?

For part a) the ordered pair is $\{(12,3),(13,13),(14,7),(15,5),(16,2),(17,17),(18,3),(19,19),(20,5)\}$.
Is it correct?

For part b) the range is $\{3,13,7,5,2,17,3,,19,5\}$. Is that the proper way to write the range, or should it be be smallest to largest with no repeating numbers like this: $\{2,3,5,7,13,17,19\}$?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The range should have no repeated numbers, but ordering them is optional.  (Sorting makes it more readable. $\{17,3,7,5,13,2,19\}$ is as correct but cruel to whoever reads your answer.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll just sort them i guess